# Solr counts by category

Tags: solr

Let's say I have a bunch of records in a solr database in various categories: Products, Pages, etc. Is there a way to get a count so I can display total matched vs. total in category.

Something like:

> **You searched for "breakfast"**
>
> Pages matching breakfast: **37**/500
>   Products matching breakfast: **7**/100

and so on.

Bonus points if I can get this in some kind of structure I can loop through, ala this pseudocode:

```
print "You searched for %s\n" % term
for category, match_count, total_count in categories:
    print "%ss matching %s: %d/%d\n" % (category, match_count, total_count)
```

This is language agnostic, I plan on accessing the solr index directly using a GET request, not using any API.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Given

**Schema** (3 fields, all of type string (solr.StrField)):

- id
- title
- category

**Input data**:

- 4 categories - Product, Page, Post, Other
- 4 titles - breakfast, lunch, dinner, supper

**Index**:

- 1000 documents with random title/category

### Request

We can use [faceting](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Faceting) in order to count specific results:

- Search query (searching for all document):

  > q=*:*
- Filter query (filtering for specific input request and marking it with tag):

  > &fq={!tag=dt}title:breakfast
- Faceting:

  - Turn on faceting

    > &facet=true
  - Turn off the results if there is only a need for category information

    > &rows=0
  - Get matching count

    > &facet.field=category
  - Get total count (count for each category excluding provided filterQuery)

    > &facet.field={!ex=dt key=total_category}category

Final query will be like this:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/stack19733827/select?q=*%3A*&fq=%7B!tag%3Ddt%7Dtitle%3Abreakfast&rows=0&wt=xml&indent=true&facet=true&facet.field=category&facet.field={!ex=dt%20key=total_category}category
```

### Result

Here a sample response which also contains the request:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>

<lst name="responseHeader">
  <int name="status">0</int>
  <int name="QTime">1</int>
  <lst name="params">
    <str name="q">*:*</str>
    <arr name="facet.field">
      <str>category</str>
      <str>{!ex=dt key=total_category}category</str>
    </arr>
    <str name="indent">true</str>
    <str name="fq">{!tag=dt}title:breakfast</str>
    <str name="rows">0</str>
    <str name="wt">xml</str>
    <str name="facet">true</str>
    <str name="_">1383337530565</str>
  </lst>
</lst>
<result name="response" numFound="262" start="0">
</result>
<lst name="facet_counts">
  <lst name="facet_queries"/>
  <lst name="facet_fields">
    <lst name="category">
      <int name="other">75</int>
      <int name="page">65</int>
      <int name="product">62</int>
      <int name="post">60</int>
    </lst>
    <lst name="total_category">
      <int name="other">260</int>
      <int name="product">253</int>
      <int name="page">250</int>
      <int name="post">237</int>
    </lst>
  </lst>
  <lst name="facet_dates"/>
  <lst name="facet_ranges"/>
</lst>
</response>
```

It contains needed information in facets:

- **total_category** - total number of documents in category
- **category** - number of documents in category which matched the filter query
- **name** of the facet - name of the category

Bonus:

- Total match for breakfast in title - 262 in all categories

Comment: Wow, awesome. Works like a charm.