# Restrict multi field facet calculation to subset of possible values

Tags: solr, faceted-search

I have a non trivial SOLR query, which already involves a filter query and facet calculations over multiple fields. One of the facet fields is a a multi value integer field, that is used to store categories. There are many possible categories and new ones are created dynamically, so using multiple fields is not an option.

What I want to do, is to restrict facet calculation over this field to a certain set of integers (= categories). So for example I want to calculate facets of this field, but only taking categories 3,7,9 and 15 into account. All other values in that field should be ignored.

How do I do that? Is there some build in functionality which can be used to solve this? Or do I have to write a custom search component?

Comment: So.. the results should contain documents with any category(1,2,3...), but facets should only have the information about categories 3,7,9,15 ? In other words you want to apply specific filter query only to the facet part of the results, but not to the documents part, correct?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want to have. Looks like I could solve it via facet prefixes, but I still have to evaluate it.

Comment: Hmm... There is a way to do it vice versa(that is - exluding fq from the facet results) if that would be of any help to someone answering this question. For example, [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19735132/935083).

Comment: And it would not be an option to execute the same query with an altered filter query? Just to populate that facet. As Solr does a good job of caching.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter can be defined for each field specified by the facet.field parameter – you can do it, by adding a parameter like this: `facet.field_name.prefix`.

Comment: here is an example for this: http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=*%3A*&fl=categories&wt=json&indent=true&facet=true&facet.field=categories&facet.mincount=1&f.categories.facet.prefix=Kinderzimmer%2F&facet.field=medienart

facet.field=categories maps to f.categories. and then just add the prefix
its for solr 4 maybe it is different in older versions

Comment: @beagle Thank you for your answer!  The example lead me to a solution for a faceting issue we have with our system.  If a user requests a facet on our metadata field, it will cause a HUGE hit on our system.  adding  `<str name="f.metadata.facet.limit">0</str>`  as in invariant in the RequestHandlers shorted out the facet and cut our query times from 72000 ms to 2000 ms.!!   SO gold right there!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about any way to define the facet base that should be different from the result, but one can use the *facet.query* to explicitly define ***each*** facet filter, e.g.:

```
facet.query={!key=3}category:3&facet.query={!key=7}category:7&facet.query={!key=9}category:9&facet.query={!key=15}category:15
```

Given the solr schema/data from this [gist](https://gist.github.com/rchukh/a29d1e294e49befe2c9a), the results will have something like this:

```
"facet_counts": {
    "facet_queries": {
      "3": 1,
      "7": 1,
      "9": 0,
      "15": 0
    },
    "facet_fields": {
      "category": [
        "2",
        2,
        "1",
        1,
        "3",
        1,
        "7",
        1,
        "8",
        1
      ]
    },
    "facet_dates": {},
    "facet_ranges": {}
}
```

Thus giving the needed facet result.

I have some doubts about performance here(especially when there will be more than 4 categories and if the initial query is returning a lot of results), so it is better to do some benchmarking, before using this in production.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the answer to my own question, but the solution we are using now: The numbers I want to filter on, build distinct groups. So we can prefix the id with a group id like this:

```
1.3
1.8
1.9
2.4
2.5
2.11
...
```

Having the data like this in SOLR, we can use facted prefixes to facet only over a single group: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#facet.prefix